# Php mail function error, mail sent from wrong address

Tags: php, email

I would like to sent e-mail to registered users with the following code:

```
    $to = $ownerMail; 
    $subject = 'SGKM - Online Ticket';
    $message = 'SGKM - Online Ticket';
    $headers = 'From: sgkm@ku.edu.tr' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: sgkm@ku.edu.tr' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

but unfortunately, in mail: "from sgkm@ku.edu.tr via venus.nswebhost.com" so, I still see venus.nswebhost.com in sender's mail part. Can't I delete that ?

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, for starters, it would probably help if you used the `$headers` variable you've defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're not using the `$headers` variable in your `mail()` function.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

mail($to, $subject, $message, **$headers**);

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I now changed the e-mail address but in mail:
"from sgkm@ku.edu.tr via venus.nswebhost.com" 
so, I still see venus.nswebhost.com in sender's mail part.
Can't I delete that ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the 'additional_parameters' flag in the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) call to specify an "envelope".

```
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f webmaster@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the $headers variable you've set up! Try:

```
 $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```