# Gmail considering my email as phishing?

Tags: php, html, email, phishing

I send an email to my customers with a receipt. I am using my server to send this email from my business email @gmail.com and it contains a link to the receipt image on my server. However, gmail labels it as possibly phishing, specifically that it is not from my business email address. What can I do to stop it from claiming it as phishing?

```
<?php
   $mifb = $_GET["mifb"]; //link to the receipt pic on my server
  $tpppp = $_GET["tpppp"]; //customer email
   $fyppp = $_GET["fyppp"]; //my business email @gmail.com
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: <'. $tpppp.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <'. $fyppp.'>' . "\r\n";
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href="http://www.mybusinesswebsite.com"><img src= '.$mifb.'></a>The receipt is in an image format</body></html>';

mail($tpppp, 'For Customer George Walters', $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Is the `From` field filled with a GMail-address?

Comment: That's because your `From` header doesn't match the envelope sender. You can add a fifth parameter, `-f` to `mail()` to fix this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7519120/3794472. In your case, you should use something like SwiftMailer and relay through GMail's SMTP server because the spf records will be incorrect, causing your mail to still go to spam. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3536836/3794472

Comment: How would I use Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance in my code @Jeremiah Winsley? -f did not fix it.

Comment: Try http://nuclearprojects.com/blog/setting-up-swift-mailer-to-send-through-google-apps-smtp-servers/ for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SMTP for proper sending your email via gmail. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837/4362168

Alternative try to use services like [mandrill](http://mandrill.com), [postmark](https://postmarkapp.com) or amazon ses
It's pretty simple to setup, and they will guide you through the process o setting proper spf and dkim records for your domain so emails you send will be more trustworthy.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.  It's OK to recommend an alternative, but you really should answer the specific question first, THEN recommend something else.

Comment: Thanks! Will do next time.

Comment: I would recommend editing your answer NOW.  It may be deleted if you do not.